# How can i avoid java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, input

when i add the text input xml tag like the one below

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

i get the error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean the project and try running again.
I think this will solve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).